# Magento 2 send multiple attachment in single mail

Tags: magento2

I sent a single file attachment. Now i need to send multiple attachment in single mail.Attachment will be in different format like .pdf,.jpeg,.png.

etc\di.xml

```
<preference for="\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" type="\Vendor\Module\Magento\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" />
```

and in my TransportBuilder.php file

```
 <?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Magento\Mail\Template;

class TransportBuilder extends \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
{
    public function addAttachment($file, $name)
    {
        if (!empty($file) && file_exists($file)) {
            $this->message
                ->createAttachment(
                    file_get_contents($file),
                    \Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
                    \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
                    \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
                    basename($name)
                );
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

and in my post.php

```
$from = ['email' => $fromEmail, 'name' => $fromName];
        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
        $templateOptions = [
            'area' => Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
            'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
        ];
        try {
            $transport = $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($template)
                ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
                ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
                ->setFrom($from)
                ->addTo($to)
                ->addAttachment($file, $name)
                ->getTransport();
            $transport->sendMessage();
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->helper->printLog($e->getMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think adding multiple `addAttachment` function will work for you.

```
$transport = $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($template)
                ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
                ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
                ->setFrom($from)
                ->addTo($to)
                ->addAttachment($file, $name)
                ->addAttachment($file2, $name2)
                ->getTransport();
```

Because if you debug the code for `Zend_Mail::addAttachment`

```
public function addAttachment(Zend_Mime_Part $attachment)
{
    $this->addPart($attachment);
    $this->hasAttachments = true;

    return $this;
}
```

which uses `Zend_Mime_Message::addPart()` function.

```
public function addPart(Zend_Mime_Part $part)
{
    /**
     * @todo check for duplicate object handle
     */
    $this->_parts[] = $part;
}
```

Which generates array for the available parts. So, using `addAttachment` multiple times will only add more values to the `$_parts` array.